# How can I assign different Scheduling time in different classes of java web application

Tags: java

As mentioned below I have three classes I want to set a scheduler using quartz api in my class which is given below.

```
class Excel{
    public void readFile(File file){
        //here we place some logic
    }
}

class Xml{
    public void readFile(File file){
        //here we place some logic
    }
}

class Text{
    public void readFile(File file){
        //here we place some logic
    }
}
```

After this I make one servlet class which control the scheduler
in class level I want to create above three class object in controller class after creating these class object I want to set time like Excel class `readFile(File file)` method execute every 3 hour,
  Xml class readFile(File file)method execute every 5 hour and Text class `readFile(File file)` method execute every 7 hour

```
public class Myschedular imlements Job{
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context){
        //here i want to call all these three class method .How can i do this.
    }
}

//I don`t want to write any code repeated in this class
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO. Please take a look at the FAQ on how to ask proper question (at least please put some effort into formatting your question so that it doesn't become a pain to read - did that for you to some extent but please think of that the next time).

Comment: Surely you have tried a few things already, please provide the code of your best attempt and the concrete doubts you have on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Hint: register 3 jobs that run at different intervals and read the different types of files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the annotation @Scheduled (spring) on each single (class) job.

The documentation is here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: By using this we can`t stop scheduling.But i want to stop scheduling also.